# Adding data from a column in a data table to a collection in Power Apps

Tags: collections, powerbi, powerapps

Please see the attached image of the app. I have a data table that views the data when the user selects something on a power BI report. I want to get the data from the contact id column and the data from the text fields(subject,description) into a collection when the button is clicked. I have the following code in the button but it does not work. The contact id is not getting added to the collection.

[image]

```
Collect(
DVdetails,
 {
 Subject: I_Subject.Text,
 Description: I_Description.Text,
 MyContactID: ContactID_Column3.Text
 }
 )
```

I want the collection as:

```
 ContactID  Subject Description
 FF388...   ddd dd
 FF413...   ddd dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Collect(
    DVdetails,
    {
        MyContactID: TableName.Selected.ContactID,
        Subject: I_Subject.Text,
        Description: I_Description.Text
    }
)
```

I don't know if you noticed, but you need to select the row that you want to do something with. So, to let powerapps know that you are talking about the *selected row*, you need to it that way.
Let me know if you have more questions. Best Regards